# How would you apply these beveled cuts into this model?

Tags: modeling

I'm at a loss on how to even google what to do here.  Please see images for reference.

The gold crown made of EVA foam is what I'm roughly modeling here.

[expired image]

Here is an image of my current model in Blender.
[image: Blender Model of Circlet]

How would you go about making those cut lines on the gold EVA one in Blender?

Is there a tutorial you would recommend?  A technique you know of?  Any ideas on a direction to go?

Comment: Did you forget to link references ?

Answer (score 7):

Since you want to slightly bend it, subdivision modeling is the way to go.
You'll need enough geometry to prevent artifacts :).

1. Create the base topology (follow my gif)
2. Select the three ridges and bevel them with 2 segments
3. Give the shape thickness, and move some of the faces up

Add Subdivision Modifier to smooth it out, 2 levels should be enough.

<sup>*Topology and beveling the ridges*</sup>
[image]

<sup>*Added thickness, and pushing up the faces*</sup>
[image]

<sup>*The result can be twisted without artifacts*</sup>
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you been nicking chunks out of UV spheres?  (That's what I was going to do, before you answered so perfectly..) :)

Comment: That seems like such an elegant solution :)). C'mon Robin, post your answer too :).

Comment: Nope :) the result isn't nearly as nice as yours, OP can take the hint if he wants to.

Comment: This looks great!  I'll see about following your directions... I'm VERY new to all this.  

Side question:  How did you do the bend?  I used Edit Mode > Mesh > Transform > Bend and it was VERY tricky to get 'just right'.  I must have played with it for 30 minutes.  Wondering if you had a different technique.  Thx!

Comment: Hi :). I used the Simple deform modifier > Bend. It keeps things procedural, so you can always adjust it later.

Comment: Hi @MorganMains :). I added the file for download. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you @jachymmichal !